# How can I change WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) terminal font color in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I noticed that if I open WSL terminal natively it doesn't have these bright colors and it's much more visible... When I change VSCODE's color theme terminal font coloring follows but never gets better :)

***vscode color theme #1***

[image: **color theme #1**]

***vscode color theme #2***

[image: color theme #2]

***native WSL terminal***

[image: Native WSL terminal]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot change at all the vscode terminal colors (neither on wsl) as those are defined at `workbench.colorCustomisations` setting.

These are the available customisation keys provided at [VSCode Theme Color](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors):

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "terminal.background":"#1D2021",
      "terminal.foreground":"#A89984",
      "terminalCursor.background":"#A89984",
      "terminalCursor.foreground":"#A89984",
      "terminal.ansiBlack":"#1D2021",
      "terminal.ansiBlue":"#0D6678",
      "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#665C54",
      "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#0D6678",
      "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#8BA59B",
      "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#95C085",
      "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#8F4673",
      "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FB543F",
      "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FDF4C1",
      "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FAC03B",
      "terminal.ansiCyan":"#8BA59B",
      "terminal.ansiGreen":"#95C085",
      "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#8F4673",
      "terminal.ansiRed":"#FB543F",
      "terminal.ansiWhite":"#A89984",
      "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FAC03B"
}
```

There is a good website with some color templates: [VSCode Base 16 Themes](https://glitchbone.github.io/vscode-base16-term/#/)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do! I added all keys and played around with values and removed unnecessary keys. Thank you!